# How to stop Apex interactive report subscription email aleet

Tags: oracle-apex

How to stop interactive report subscription email in apex for particular user

- M Kani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be Workspace Administrator to do this.

1. Log into the workspace
2. Go to Administration
3. On the right side of the page you have Tasks list; click on Manage Interactive Report Settings
4. Click on Subscriptions
5. Select the subscription you want to delete and press the delete button.